# RDLC report export correctly from chrome browser, but not render

Tags: rdlc

RDLC report get export correctly from chrome browser, but not render.
Same report get render and export correctly into firefox browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all browsers or versions are supported. You must use a browser that has script support enabled. If the browser cannot run scripts, you cannot view the report.

**Source:**
[Browser Support for ReportViewer Web Server Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251673.aspx)

It's also possible that a layout fix might solve your problem:
[Gotcha: Reporting Services Viewer bugs on Google Chrome](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2011/06/28/Gotcha-Reporting-Services-Viewer-bugs-on-Google-Chrome.aspx)

Comment: Gotcha: Reporting Services Viewer bugs on Google Chrome. Is working but Print button not displaying.